# Merge two dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
df1:

Person    Value
Jack        6
Jill        9
Sam         4
Tony        3


df2:

Home    Away
Jill    Sam
Tony    Jack
```

I wish to make a 3rd dataframe which grabs the number in the Value column from df1 and matches them to the names in df2

Goal output:

```
df3:

Home    Away    Value1    Value2
Jill    Sam       9         4
Tony    Jack      3         6
```

Is there a simple merge function I can perform on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the dataframes in machine readable code, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for both columns:

```
s = df1.set_index('Person')['Value']

df2['Value1'] = df2['Home'].map(s)
df2['Value2'] = df2['Away'].map(s)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new `DataFrame`:

```
s = df1.set_index('Person')['Value']
df3 = df2.assign(Value1 = df2['Home'].map(s),
                 Value2 = df2['Away'].map(s))
print (df3)
   Home  Away  Value1  Value2
0  Jill   Sam       9       4
1  Tony  Jack       3       6
```

Solution with double [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and `rename` columns:

```
df3 = (df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Person':'Home','Value':'Value1'}), how='left')
          .merge(df1.rename(columns={'Person':'Away','Value':'Value2'}), how='left'))
print (df3)
   Home  Away  Value1  Value2
0  Jill   Sam       9       4
1  Tony  Jack       3       6
```